# Pinia Vue3 - How to return a spread operator object?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have an API to get user information like this:

```
{
  name: 'John Doe',
  birthday: '2000-01-01',
  email: 'john@doe.com'
  ...
}
```

I have a Pinia store called `userStore` to handle all User-related data, including calling that API.

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUserStore= defineStore('user', () => {
  const profile = ref({});

  async function queryProfile() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://mysite.test/api/profile');
    profile.value = response.data;
  }

  return {
    profile,
    queryProfile,
  }
});
```

It works but I don't like how I need to write `userStore.profile.name` to get the data.

I prefer if we can directly call `userStore.name`.

I tried spreading the `profile` like this but doesn't work (no error message, the store is empty when checked with devtools):

```js
return {
  ...profile,
  queryProfile,
};
```

I also tried using `toRefs`, but same error:

```
return {
  ...toRefs(profile),
  queryProfile,
};
```

Technically I can go the dirty-route and do this:

```js
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useUserStore= defineStore('user', () => {
  const name = ref('');
  const birthday = ref('');
  const email = ref('');

  async function queryProfile() {
    const response = await axios.get('http://mysite.test/api/profile');
    name.value = response.data.name;
    birthday.value = response.data.birthday;
    email.value = response.data.email;
  }

  return {
    name,
    birthday,
    email,
    queryProfile,
  }
});
```

But I have a lot of fields in the Profile, so this is the last resort if no other way.

Thanks before.

Comment: You need to reconsider the way data is stored. First of all, function store is for low-level things. If you can't benefit from them, use options store. You don't really need refs there, you could do `Object.assign(this, response.data)`. You may still want to keep `profile` a separate property because it appears to be a separate entity. If you don't want long paths like userStore.profile.name, that's what getters/computeds are for

Comment: Hi @EstusFlask thanks for the reply, I will use getters as you recommend.

Comment: @hrsetyono, If your question is answered, it would be nice to close the question, so that it is clear, that you solved it.